# $P(\max\{ X,Y \} \leq aX)$. Is it correct?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables which have exponential distributions of parameters $\lambda, \nu$ respectively, and $a \geq 1$. Calculate $$P(\max\{ X,Y \} \leq aX)$$
My work is this:
$$P(\max\{ X,Y \} \leq aX) = P(X\leq aX; Y \leq aX)=P(X\leq aX)\cdot P(Y\leq aX)$$
We know that $P(X\leq aX) =1$ since $a\geq 1$ so we only have to calculate $P(Y\leq aX)$
$$P(Y\leq aX)=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{ax}f_{X}(x)f_Y(y)\:dy\: dx = 
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{ax} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\nu e^{-\nu y} \: dy \: dx = \frac{a\nu}{a\nu + \lambda}$$
However I am not sure if this is correct because I got a solution from a teacher and it was this:
$$\frac{\nu}{\nu + \lambda} + \frac{\lambda}{1+\nu a - \nu}$$
Could someone tell me if I messed up and where please?

Comment: I don't see why the events $X\le aX$ and $Y\le aX$ should be independent (except for the fact that $X\le aX$ has probability $1$).

Comment: Not that the observation makes a difference, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you have calculated, $ \frac{a\nu}{a\nu+\lambda}$ is indeed correct. The answer given by your teacher seems to be wrong. Here is a small check. For, $a \to \infty$ the probability should tend to 1.